# c++ applcation for linux to convert ipv4 packet to ipv6

Tags: c++, linux, sockets, network-programming, linux-kernel

I'm looking to develope a c/c++ application for linux that converts ipv4 packet received to ipv6 and viceversa ( losing some ipv6 only features )

step 1: how to receive all necessary info from an incoming packet? Should I use raw packet   library to read all TCP/UDP flags and info about the packet?
Any documentation about that? ( I'm already looking at beej.us guide)

step2: i'm looking to use this program into a linux machine (ie Ubuntu) as a router to forward all packets received from an ipv6 machine to a net card, to an ipv4 machine connected to the ipv4 card on the router.

How to receive and parse all packets in this application ( except the packets directed to the router machine IP ) ? Is it possible in the 'application level' or should I touch the kernel? If yes, where could i get some documentation about this?

Goal: have an http or other common protocol works between the 2 machines connected via the router

Greatly appreciate any hints

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since converting between IPv4 and IPv6 necessarily implies changing IP addresses in the packet, NAT is required by definition. Your project comes down to implenting a NAT router.

Read up on [NAT64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NAT64) to find out more about the particular flavour of NAT you are looking for.

In the course of trying to implement a router in userspace, I think that [tun](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TUN/TAP) devices are probably the best design choice for sending and receiving packets. This is in fact the approach chosen by [TAYGA](http://www.litech.org/tayga/) (the first NAT64 implementation listed on the above-cited Wikipedia page).

Implementing a router (of any type, let alone a NAT) in userspace is a fairly complex and ambitious project, so the best two pieces of advice I can give are:

- Do not implement this yourself. Instead, contribute your efforts to improving one of the existing open source implementations.
- Failing that, study one of the existing open source implementations for inspiration.